# HTML5 start-screen Image placement on screen

Tags: html, image

I'm making a start screen, and i have a image acting as a button, and i have completely forgot how to position it on the page to where i want it to be.

```
<div id="SplashScreen" width="400" height="400">
    <h1>Game Title</h1>
    <img id="StartButton" src="play.png"/>
</div>
```

How would i place this where i want it on the screen? I don't mind how it is coded as i know

BTW I'm new to html, So please excuse my noob questions :)

Comment: _How would i place this where i want it on the screen?_ - No one here can read your mind.  Where do you want it on the screen?

Comment: It dose not really matter where i want it, i'm asking how to place it some where, you could put any value into the code.

Comment: Well depending on where you want it and the content of the rest of your page, the answer might be completely different...

Comment: Well basicly all that will be on the screen will be the button.

Comment: you want centered div and CSS to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In html there are a few main ways to position content.
Here is a link to all the different ways to position content:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Practically the most common way for a splash screen might be absolute positioning.

```
<div id="SplashScreen" width="400" height="400" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:100;">
    <h1>Game Title</h1>
    <img id="StartButton" src="play.png"/>
</div>
```

This will position the splash in the top left of the browser.  top:0 will cause it to be 0 units from the top, left:0 will cause it to be 0 units from the left.  If you wanted to adjust these you could do so, but remember to add units, as in top:400px;

I also added in a z-index, so that it will appear on top of any other content you have on the page.

One last thing, just as a note, you should use classes instead of styles for positioning.  that is much easier to maintain.

```
<style>
.splashScreen {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:100;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}
</style>
```

would be the class and to use it, you could replace what you have with this:

```
 <div id="SplashScreen" class="splashScreen">
    <h1>Game Title</h1>
    <img id="StartButton" src="play.png"/>
</div>
```

As the comments above have mentioned, this is to get you started, if you want it positioned in the center of the screen, or relative to something else, you would have to make adjustments to the class.

GL!